# In ZFC without a few redundant axioms, does removing the dependence of the predicate/WFF on the domain set in the replacement axiom weaken the theory?

Tags: set-theory

Given ZFC without the redundant axioms of specification, empty set, and pairing (please tell me if I should be more specific about what I mean here since I'm new to ZFC, I can write down more specifically what I mean, I just thought it would clutter the question though), if we change the axiom of replacement from:

> Let $\Phi(x,y,z_1,z_2,...,z_n,S)$ be a WFF of ZFC whose free variables are $x,y,z_1,z_2,...,z_n,S$. Then $\forall z_1,...,z_n\forall S(\forall x\in S\exists!y\Phi(x,y,z_1,z_2,...,z_n,S)\implies\exists R\forall y(y\in R\iff\exists x\in S\Phi(x,y,z_1,z_2,...,z_n,S))).$

to:

> Let $\Phi(x,y,z_1,z_2,...,z_n)$ be a WFF of ZFC whose free variables are $x,y,z_1,z_2,...,z_n$. Then $\forall z_1,...,z_n\forall S(\forall x\in S\exists!y\Phi(x,y,z_1,z_2,...,z_n)\implies\exists R\forall y(y\in R\iff\exists x\in S\Phi(x,y,z_1,z_2,...,z_n))).$

(in the second version $S$ is no longer free in $\Phi$) is the resulting system weaker than the standard ZFC?

---

Ok that's a formal statement of my question, but I know that I need to provide some more context.

1. Informally, I understand the axiom schema of replacement to mean that the image of a set (the set here being $S$) under any definable function exists, except with two modifications: function is not used like a "function" in proper set theory here, a subset of a domain and codomain, instead the function is given as a predicate (i.e. the $\Phi$), and secondly in the axiom $\Phi$ extends to include general N-ary predicates possibly depending on some other parameters $z_1,z_2,...,z_n$. I don't see where the dependence on this 'domain set' $S$ ought to come from.
2. Finally for background, I'm self-studying this and am just interested in trying to understand this axiom a bit better. In one of my lines of thought, it seems like the $S$ that differs between them is irrelevant since you can take the second version with $z_1,...,z_n,z_{n+1}$ and then instantiate the $n+1^\text{th}$ parameter $z_{n+1}$ as $S$, but this seems a little sketchy for some reason. I'm not sure though that I really know how to explain why it feels sketchy without risking going off on a tangent and making the question unclear though. In any case, what the 'conventional' wisdom on this topic is would be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing sketchy about it. That's a correct argument that the two schemes are equivalent. (Incidentally, replacement is equivalent to replacement with no parameters at all, but that takes some work to show.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen can you show it? I'd be very happy to accept it as an answer. And does it work if you substitute R in for one of the parameters, too?

Comment: I assume you meant show that your two schemes are equivalent in more detail, so I posted an answer. (But if you meant the result about replacement with no parameters, see [here](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schlicht/ZFC_without_parameters.pdf).) As to your question about $R,$ no, that won't work. Note that in using replacement you only existentially instantiate $R$ after you have universally instantiated the parameters. Really, one should be explicit in the statement of replacement that $R$ is not free in $\Phi,$ though I think that's reasonably clear from the way you phrased it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you haven't written down the replacement scheme quite correctly. What was probably intended was  $$\forall z_1,...,z_n\forall S(\forall x\in S\exists!y\;\Phi(x,y,z_1,z_2,...,z_n,S)\\\implies\exists R\forall y(y\in R\iff\exists x\in S\;\Phi(x,y,z_1,z_2,...,z_n,S)))$$ (and with a similar modification for the other version).

That aside, the idea you give in your second bullet is a correct argument that the two versions you give are equivalent. In a little more detail, let $z_1,\ldots z_n$ and $S$ be any sets. We need to show $$\forall x\in S\exists!y\;\Phi(x,y,z_1,z_2,...,z_n,S)\implies\exists R\forall y(y\in R\iff\exists x\in S\;\Phi(x,y,z_1,z_2,...,z_n,S))).$$ Per your idea, consider the an instance of the second version of replacement $$\forall z_1,...,z_{n+1}\forall S(\forall x\in S\exists!y\;\Phi(x,y,z_1,z_2,...,z_n, z_{n+1})\implies\exists R\forall y(y\in R\iff\exists x\in S\;\Phi(x,y,z_1,z_2,...,z_n, z_{n+1}))).$$  and instantiate the outer universal quantifiers as $z_i=z_i$ for $i=1,\ldots n,$ $z_{n+1}$ as $S$ and $S$ as $S,$ and then we have exactly what we needed to show.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that typo! I've fixed it in the question.